# Help me about the complex power in circuit analysis?

Tags: power

In circuit analysis, the complex power is S = P + jQ. For the avarage power P, we can use wattmetter to measure P. But how we can measure the reactive power Q in the circuit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To measure reactive power you use a [VAR meter](http://lightstar.co.kr/down/vm_kai.pdf).

[image]

The indicated number is \$V \times A \times sin(\theta)\$, so the indication will be zero for a resistive load.

Answer (score 0):

Digital Multimeters, Varmeters, or Power Monitors could give you the result immediately.

Another approach is to find the power factor angle using a dual-trace oscilloscope, and then using the equation: [image]